# Different scale on apps (one display)

Tags: display, display-resolution, thinkpad

I'm still getting used to Ubuntu (20.04) on my Lenovo ThinkPad Carbon X1 after being a Mac user for 10 years.

When setting up, I found the resolution made things far too tiny and I'm sure I changed a few things, including the scale slider (first) and then I dropped my resolution (from 3840x2160 to 1920x1080). The resolution change made everything look ok, except Telegram, which I think is still being scaled and looks really large.

But now I can't find the scale slider any more and can't find how to make it look 'normal'...

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Did you enable fractional scaling or did you just decrease the resolution?

Comment: I believe that 3480X2160 is the one being scaled. 1920X1080 is fullHD. That is a very common default mode. In the terminal type `man xrandr` and read the result. When you change the mode (resolution) xrandr automatically adjusts the scale to compensate.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I didn't enable fractional scaling; I didn't like the sound of that. I only decreased the resolution.

Comment: @NateT typing `xrandr` give a lot of info that I know nothing about :D 

It lists this at the top:
`Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 2520, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected 1920x1080+356+1440 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm`